# need help translating a code snippet from java to C# equivalent

Tags: java, c#, arraylist, xamarin, code-translation

Here's the code snippet I'd like to translate from Java to C#. I'm not sure what's causing the error but I've never used ArrayLists and vectors before. Thanks in advance!!

```
//Java class definitions, constructors, fields, methods etc here. 
//sphbasis is a Vector object.

    public SphericalHarmonicDecomposition[] getSphericalHarmonicBasis() {
    return (SphericalHarmonicDecomposition[])(sphbasislist.toArray(
    new SphericalHarmonicDecomposition[sphbasislist.size()]));
}
```

I've tried doing the following in C#:

```
//C# class definitions, constructors, fields, methods etc here. 
//sphbasis is a ArrayList object.

    public SphericalHarmonicDecomposition[] getSphericalHarmonicBasis() {
    return (SphericalHarmonicDecomposition[])(sphbasislist.ToArray(
    new SphericalHarmonicDecomposition[sphbasislist.Count]));
    }
```

I get the following errors. I'm using Mono and Xamarin studio on a mac.

```
Error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 
`System.Collections.ArrayList.ToArray(System.Type)' 
has some invalid arguments (CS1502) (projectx)
```

and

```
Error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert    
`matdcal.engine.model.SphericalHarmonicDecomposition[]' expression 
to type `System.Type' (CS1503) (projectx)
```

Comment: You should probably use a generic list anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following. In Java you need to pass an array to the `toArray` method, but that's not correct in C# (.NET).

```
//C# class definitions, constructors, fields, methods etc here. 
//sphbasis is a ArrayList object.

    public SphericalHarmonicDecomposition[] getSphericalHarmonicBasis() {
    return (SphericalHarmonicDecomposition[])(sphbasislist.ToArray());
    }
```

### References

[Java ArrayList.toArray](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.util/ArrayListtoArrayTa.htm)

[C# List.ToArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)